# Giving maximum priority to some traffic

Tags: linux, networking, tc, traffic, delay

I have all my interfaces configured as follows:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 20
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 10.0Mbit burst 15k
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 1.0Mbit ceil 10.0mbit prio 1 burst 15k
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 9.0Mbit ceil 10.0mbit prio 7 burst 15k
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:10 handle 10: sfq perturb 10 limit 64 quantum 10000
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:20 handle 20: sfq perturb 10 limit 64 quantum 10000
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 handle 10 fw flowid 1:10

+ IPTABLES
```

Having a priority queue for some special traffic reduces the delay when the network is congested. However, it is not enough. I would like some packets to be sent as soon as they arrive to the queues so I do not want to delay them never. How can I achieve that?